# automatically download POEditor translations via xCode build phase

Tags: xcode, translation

I am using POEditor.com for managing the translations of apps. They have an REST API that should allow to automatically fetch the translations each time we do a build in xCode. I want to share the bash script I have written to do this (answering my own question :)

Answer (score 6):

Create a tools folder in your main folder structure, and copy the below provided "poeditorfetch" script in it:

[image]

[image]
Add a new build phase "POEditor translations" to your xCode configuration:

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#update these values with the values for your project => go to the POEditor website / API integration
POEDITOR_API_TOKEN="a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j10klmnopqrstuvw"
POEDITOR_PROJECT_ID="123456"
#because the language code for POEditor can differ from the code used by xCode we must specify the poeditorcode->xCodecode
#this is also handy to download eg. xCode's Base language from English for example!
POEDITOR_LANGUAGES_VS_XCODE_FOLDERS=("en->Base" "en->en" "fr-be->fr" "nl->nl")
ROOT_LOCALIZATION_FOLDER="./resource/translations/"

#extractUrlFromPOEditorJson function which extracts the url from $json global variable
function extractUrlFromPOEditorJson {
    temp=`echo $json | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w item`
    echo ${temp##*|}
}

#downloads the strings file for one language, uses currentLanguageCodePOEditor, currentLangaugeCodeXCode as input variables and the POEDITOR_xxx and ROOT_LOCALIZATION_FOLDER as constants
function downloadOneLanguage {
    outputfile=$ROOT_LOCALIZATION_FOLDER$currentLangaugeCodeXCode".lproj/Localizable.strings"
    #first fetech the download url from po editor
    echo "*************** $currentLanguageCodePOEditor ->  $outputfile ***************"
    echo Fetching POEditor URL...
    json=`curl -s -# -X POST https://poeditor.com/api/ \
    -d api_token="$POEDITOR_API_TOKEN" \
    -d action="export" \
    -d id="$POEDITOR_PROJECT_ID" \
    -d language="$currentLanguageCodePOEditor" \
    -d type="apple_strings"`
    #echo $json
    url=`extractUrlFromPOEditorJson`
    #echo $url
    #fetch the actual strings file
    echo Downloading translation file...
    curl -# -s -X GET $url -o $outputfile
}

for value in "${POEDITOR_LANGUAGES_VS_XCODE_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
    currentLanguageCodePOEditor="${value%%->*}"
    currentLangaugeCodeXCode="${value##*->}"
    downloadOneLanguage
done
```